# Why is this method and for loop executing more times than I want it to?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I'm working on a Java problem set that requires a particular method to be executed N number of times (in this case, N = 5).

For some reason, though, every time I run the program, it executes (or at least, prints out) 10 times. I cannot figure out how to make it print out only 5 times.

I'm very new to programming, so apologies if this is a simple fix. Thanks for the help!

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    final int N = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        drunkWalk();
        int stepCount = drunkWalk();
        sum += stepCount;

        if (i == N)
        {
            System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals " + (sum/N));
        }
    }
}       


public static int drunkWalk ()
{

    int start = 5;                      //initializes variables
    int steps = 0;
    int position = 0;
    System.out.println ("Here we go again...time for a walk!");

    do 
    {
       int direction = retInt ();

       if (direction%2 == 0)                //Determines if it will go left, towards home/0
       {
        position = start - 1;
       }

       else                         //Determines if it will go right, towards jail/10
       {
        position = start + 1;
       }

       start = position; 

       steps++;
    } while (position != 0 && position != 10);

    System.out.println ("Took " + steps + " steps, and");

    if (position == 0)
    {
       System.out.println ("Landed at HOME");
    }

    else 
    {
       System.out.println ("Landed in JAIL");
    }

    System.out.println ();

    return steps;                                //So the sum of the # of steps can continue to be calculated for the sum in main's for loop
}

public static int retInt ()                     //Returns odd or even integer to determine the direction in drunkWalk()
{
    return (int)(6 * Math.random ());
}
```

}

Comment: try debugging the program. Execute it line by line and you'll see everything.

Comment: You're calling drunkwalk() 2 times in the for loop. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 4):

```
drunkWalk();
int stepCount = drunkWalk();
```

You literally call it twice. Remove the first one to walk just once. Note that it doesn't assign its return value either, so it wouldn't do anything with the result that's being returned.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! You're right, that absolutely worked. How do you assign the return value? That part kept messing me up as well.

Comment: You're already assigning the return value in the second line: `int stepCount = drunkWalk();`. Here the result of `drunkWalk()` is assigned to the variable `stepCount`